# Access element from ng-include html

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have an html that is included in several htmls that are controlled by several different controllers . I want to access elements from that included html by id in every controller . I will post below my html that is included in every html:

```
<ul class="nav menu" >
    <li id="tom_nav_bar"><a href="/#tom">
        <svg class="glyph stroked dashboard-dial">
            <use xlink:href="#stroked-dashboard-dial"></use>
        </svg>
        BEX Dashboard</a></li>
    <li id="sonar_nav_bar"><a href="#/sonar">
        <svg class="glyph stroked chevron right">
            <use xlink:href="#stroked-chevron-right"/>
        </svg>
        Sonar</a></li>
    <li id="teamcity_nav_bar"><a href="/#teamcity">
        <svg class="glyph stroked chevron right">
            <use xlink:href="#stroked-chevron-right"/>
        </svg>
        TeamCity</a></li>
    <li id="kpi_definitions_nav_bar"><a href="#/kpi_definitions">
        <svg class="glyph stroked chevron right">
            <use xlink:href="#stroked-chevron-right"/>
        </svg>
        Kpi Definitions</a></li>
    <li id="credit_risk_custom_report_nav_bar"><a href="#/department_custom_report">
        <svg class="glyph stroked chevron right">
            <use xlink:href="#stroked-chevron-right"/>
        </svg>
        CREDITRISK Custom Report (beta)</a></li>
</ul>
```

Let's name the code html : navbar.html. Now I will post one from 4 htmls where I included the above code:

```
<div ng-include src="'navbar.html'" class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 sidebar"></div>
```

And now in my controllers I want to access for example 'tom_nav_bar' id , but I'm not able to do it:

```
document.getElementById("tom_nav_bar").className = "active";
```

Here getElementById is returning null.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing that, it's not an Angular way. But anyway, use getElementById() with $watch.

Comment: @JackBauer can you give me an example , how can I use $watch ? Thanks

Comment: @CosminOprea, please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40397280/2545680) for the correct way of how to do it. If you still want to have it your way, show the full code of a controller, because the availability of inserted elements depends on when this line `document.getElementById("tom_nav_bar").className = "active";` is executed

Comment: @CosminOprea, you're welcome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't access DOM from the controllers. This is almost impossible to test, hard to refactor and adds confusion because DOM manipulation is mixed with presentation logic

I suggest you create a simple directive 'insert-navbar' with the following template:

```
<div ng-include src="'navbar.html'" class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 sidebar"></div>
```

and use it like this in every place it needs to be used:

```
<insert-navbar>
```

Then, inside the `link` function of that directive you should be able to access the element like this:

```
link: function(scope, element) {
  element[0].querySelector('#tom_nav_bar')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your syntax might be wrong https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

Also, maybe because your partial hasnt loaded yet at the moment of calling

```
document.getElementById
```

try putting this in your scripts:

```
function GetElement(idselector) {
    document.getElementById(idselector).className = "active";
}
```

and then when you include your navbar, use this function in the onload parameter of ng-include:

```
<div 
    ng-include="navbar.html" 
    [onload=GetElement("tom_nav_bar")]
    class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 sidebar">
</div>
```